# Check if Direct Acyclic Graph has no Cycle?

Tags: spring, grails, graph, grails-orm, grails-2.0

Assume I have the following directed graph structure:

```
class GraphNode {
    static hasMany = [children: GraphNode]
    static hasMany = [parents: GraphNode]
    static mappedBy = [children: 'parents', parents: 'children']
}
```

How can I restrict cycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an algorithm for that purpose:  http://adhockery.blogspot.de/2010/06/acyclic-relationship-validation-in.html

Answer (score 0):

There's no such built-in functionality in GORM.

You can write a custom validator, which traverses through the children/parents and returns error when the chain size > n.